# "Совсем не/солёная, может, чуть слаще, чем ключевая". Слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, частица-не, прилагательные

*Она отхлебнула с сомнением, но никакой разницы с обычной водой не заметила. Совсем **не солёная**, может, чуть слаще, чем ключевая.*

По правилам надо бы "не" написать с прилагательным слитно. Но рука упорно пишет раздельно. Что делать с рукой и орфографией?

Comment: Перед этим не было упоминания, что вода морская? Если она ожидала, что вода будет солёной, то в этом предложении может быть отрицание такого предположения (раздельное написание).

Comment: @ЕленаТаволга 1. Если Вас не устраивает моя правка, Вы можете её "откатить". 2. Если есть возможность, расширьте, пожалуйста, предтекст (будет понятнее всем).

Comment: @Римма Михайлова, я обожаю правки! Любые! Это интересно!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Однозначной рекомендации я не дам, хотя по смыслу я за **раздельное написание**.

Совершенно верно говорят, правила разрешают оба варианта, но ведь они не тождественны по семантике. Несоленая - это некое самостоятельное качество (несоленая еда - при некоторых лечебных диетах), а "не соленая" - отрицание солености. Вот это отрицание солености здесь вернее. И еще оно подчеркивается  усилительным "совсем".

Тут, правда, есть один косвенный довод против. Соленый - по семантике это и обычное прилагательное от "соль" и отглагольное от "солить". Так вот для отглагольное прилагательного слитное отглагольного прилагательного раздельное написание не вызывало бы вопросов (воду **не солили** - она не солёная). А у нас скорее именно обычное прилагательное. Вряд ли речь идет о том, что питьевую воду кто-то не посолил, она просто **несоленая**, это её качество. А это дает основания и для слитного написания. Вот это соображение делает мою рекомендацию не столь абсолютной.
Так что в конечном счете дела за автором, который может руководствоваться своим пониманием того, чего в этой фразе больше - отрицания или нового качества.

Comment: В словаре Ефремовой первое значение у слова «соленый» — содержащий соль. Так что отрицание вполне нормально, зачем выдумывать параллели с глаголом?

Comment: Уважаемый Мимоходов! Ваша не столь абсолютная рекомендация по-настоящему очаровательна. Как-то не связывала правописание этого слова с его принадлежностью к части речи. Вы мне открыли глаза!

Comment: Aer, благодарю за внимание к вопросу.

Comment: @ЕленаТаволга  Во-первых, давайте без уважаемых, во-вторых, ваша наивность действительно очаровательна. Вы не знали, что орфография зависит от части речи? )))) Или это только для данного случая?

Comment: @Aer а зачем вообще выдумывать грамматику не хотите спросвить? Вы не согласны, что соленый может выступать в функции причастия? "Соленые огурцы" - это содержащие соль? На Ефремову только не надо кивать, у неё все вполне корректно.

Comment: Нет, не хочу; об одном лишь прошу: придерживаться темы вопроса, все жалобы на порчу сайта вы можете высказать на Мете. Как мне показалось, вы рассматриваете только первичное значение слова *соленый*, при этом забывая о его переносных значениях, которые фиксируются словарями. Я и не говорил, что у Ефремовой что-то некорректно, прошу вас перечитать мой первый комментарий.

Comment: @Мимоходов (Как-то непривычно так обращаться). Да, я очаровательна в своей наивности и до вчерашнего дня искренне полагала, что орфография зависит исключительно от настроения пишущего.))) А данный случай кажется мне интересным вот с какой стороны. Если "соленый" - отыменное прилагательное, то с суффиксом -ен- оно относится к исключениям (типа "ветреный")? Я правда не знаю.(( Но надеюсь на вас!)))

Answer (score 3):

*Совсем не солёная, может, чуть слаще, чем ключевая.*

Я бы всё-таки написала слитно, потому что совсем = совершенно, вполне. Но Ваше желание написать раздельно тоже понятно, потому что перед отрицанием в разговорном стиле совсем = нисколько, ни в какой степени. Здесь явно разговорный стиль, так что в художественном тексте просится действительно раздельное написание, подчёркнутое отрицание.

Однако если это учебное упражнение, необходимо писать по правилам литературного языка - слитно.

Comment: _Людмила: Однако если это учебное упражнение, **необходимо** писать по правилам литературного языка - **слитно**._ === **Нет таких правил!**

Comment: Galina, Людмила, slava1947, спасибо за разъяснения. Уяснила, что есть разница в применении правил для упражнения и для художественного текста. В первом случае склоняю голову перед гуру, во втором - сама себе гуру.

Answer (score 2):

Возможны **оба варианта** написания (усиление отрицания или усиление утверждения):

http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77#pp77

7. При использовании в качестве пояснительного слова наречия **совсем** **возможно как слитное, так и раздельное написание частицы не с прилагательными,** что связано **с разными значениями, в которых употребляется слово совсем**. Ср.: совсем ненужная встреча (‘совершенно ненужная, лишняя’) — совсем не случайная встреча (‘отнюдь не случайная’).

   В некоторых случаях возможны два толкования и, как следствие, допустимы два написания: совсем небольшие достижения (‘маленькие, скромные’) — совсем не большие достижения (‘отнюдь не большие’).

Comment: Благодарю вас, Jasmin. Вы развязали мне руки.

Answer (score 1):

В вопросе о том, рассматривать "*несолёность*" как свойство воды (слитное написание) или как *отрицание факта* её "*солёности*" (раздельное) важны два обстоятельства:

a) контекст;

б) *нетипичность* для воды такого свойства, как "*несолёность*" ("неперчёность") - "несолёную" воду обычно называют "**пресной**", если речь идёт не о *сравнении* её с другой жидкостью (и здесь важен контекст).

Из самого предложения контекст не следует, поскольку можно предположить разные ситуации, предшествовавшие "дегустации":

1. Девушка была одна у моря и очень хотела пить. Она была приятно удивлена тем, что морская вода оказалась **совсем не** (=*вовсе не*) **солёной** - в *противоположность стереотипу* солёности морской воды.
2. Девушка спросонья захотела "солёненького" и хлебнула из попавшейся на глаза банки из-под огурцов. Её сомнения в получении желаемого подтвердились: там оказался не рассол, а вода, причём **совсем несолёная** (*свойство* воды *в сравнении* с желанным рассолом и степень его выраженности) и даже сладковатая.

Второй контекст гораздо менее вероятен, поэтому при отсутствии возможности объяснить свой выбор лучше остановиться на **раздельном** написании.

Comment: Alex_ander! Благодарю за подробнейшие разъяснения. Я тоже склоняюсь к стереотипу. Хотя, бывает, спросонья так хочется солененького!